# How do I adjust apple crisp cooking time for muffin-size crisps?

Tags: baking, cooking-time

My usual apple crisp recipe is [here](https://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/apple-crumble-and-vanilla-ice-cream-108716), except that I generally use a third of the recommended sugar and three or four times the necessary cinnamon.

I'd like to experiment with variations on the recipe (e.g. adding flour to the filling, putting nuts in the crumble) but I don't really want to make multiple whole apple crisps, because of lack of ingredients, lack of people to eat them, etc.

I'm thinking about making multiple mini-crisps in a muffin tin. This also has the advantage that they will be side by side for easy comparison. But I'm not sure how (if at all) to adjust the baking time. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the book Kitchen Companion, when you take a square cake and cook it as cupcakes, you cut the baking time by 40-60%, depending on the relative depths of the two pans.  I'd assume the relative cooking time for a crumble to be similar, which would mean 25-35 minutes.

There are also a number of apple crisp/crumble recipes on the web done in muffin cups or small ramekins, and their cooking times range from [14 minutes](https://chocolatecoveredkatie.com/2016/11/10/mini-apple-pies-muffin-tin/), to [25 minutes](https://www.prevention.com/food-nutrition/recipes/a20513119/muffin-tin-apple-crisps/), to [35 minutes](https://www.thegunnysack.com/mini-apple-crisps/).  The 35 minute ones sound the most similar to what you're doing, so I'd say start checking them at 20 minutes, but expect 30ish.

Comment: Also, of course, try the original recipe in a muffin tin before you try the variants, so that you know what differences the tin alone makes.